# Google Sign In failed on Firebase Android App - GoogleSignInResult@a84236f

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase with Google Signin  to authenticate a user into an android app. This app was working, but I reinstalled Ubuntu and Android Studio. Now it is not working more.

I put the email and password for authentication with Google Sign in (using email and password of Google) , the **error** returned  was 
**GoogleSignInResult@a84236f** 
the function called  that returned tis value was:

onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

What does this code mean:
**GoogleSignInResult@a84236f**?

and the result of result.isSuccess() 
is: **false**.

The function complete is:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        Log.d("DEIP","request code = 9001? ="+requestCode);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            Log.d(TAG," isSucess? result.toString  ="+result.toString());
            Log.d(TAG," +result.isSuccess()   ="+result.isSuccess());
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
                Log.d(TAG,"Failed into onActivityResult");
            }
        }
    }
```

The result when failed is:

isSucess? result.toString  =com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin**.GoogleSignInResult@a84236f** :  +result.isSuccess()   =false

Another thing, the Fingerprint I put with the command 
 keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

gives me a  **SHA1 fingerprint**, but when I put this value into Firebase console fingerprint, the firebase.console.google.com site **recognize like a SHA256** fingerprint.

May be this problem is associate with the problem above? How can I fix it?

I tried:

1. Re generate SHA1 fingerprint. - The Firebase give-me the information that my sh1 fingerprint is a 256 Finger print. I generated the release key and  the debug key too.
2. I put the new file google-services.json into the app directory of Android Studio.
3. I tried to run the app into a physical cell phone but the error was the same as into a virtual cell phone.
4. Compare the package name into file AndroidManifes.xml and this field into Firebase console.
5. Clean the project and rebuild.
6. Disable Instant Run
7. I put the new values of dependencies (9.8.0) like compile `'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'`

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
   compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'

   // Google
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'

   // Firebase
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.8.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.8.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.8.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.8.0'
   // Firebase UI
   compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'

   // Testing dependencies
   androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta3'

   //tryning to make COntrainlayout work
      //compile 'android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout'
   //

   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
   ```

   }

   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was the way I created the fingerprint.
The command

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

did not work  to me. 
The way to create the debug fingerprint was:
" 
[Basically, in Android Studio, open the Gradle menu on the far right, open android-start from the drop down (refresh if nothing is showing), open Tasks, open android, double click signingReport. 
shown in this link:
https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/issues/11
"

or this video tutorial
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_9tk7ME4ZU][2]

The Firebase team helped me with this error.

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem as well. I created my keystore and set the project to build using this keystore (in File > Project Structure menu) but my keytool generated SHA1 was different from the one shown in the Gradle menu as you mention. I added this new SHA1 in my Firebase Console and re-downloaded the json file and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I'm trying [this tutorial](http://bhardwajrish.blogspot.com.br/2016/09/firebase-auth-debug-vs-release.html..)

It said that resolve this problem in this steps:

1. Update Firebase console with SHA1 of your release keystore.
2. Re-download google-config.json file.
3. Place your release keystore in the same folder as your gradle file and update gradle with the code below.